# Removing container for the whole form

Tags: symfony, twig

When I use code like this:

```
form_widget(form)
```

it puts container on every row but also on the whole form, I use two theming files:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
<section>
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
</section>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

This one works fine on every row, but this:

```
{% block form_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {# <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}> #}
        {{ block('field_rows') }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {# </div> #}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget %}
```

removes the container not only from the form but also from every row. How can I remove the container only from the form?

// EDIT

I get:

```
<form method="post" action="/acme/web/app_dev.php/admin/users_management/3">
    <label>Edit user</label>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" value="PUT" name="_method" />
        <div id="acme_usersbundle_usertype">
            <section>
                <label class="required" for="acme_usersbundle_usertype_username">
                    Login
                    <span class="required"> </span>
                </label>
                <div>
                    <input id="acme_usersbundle_usertype_username" type="text" value="login" maxlength="255" required="required" name="acme_usersbundle_usertype[username]">
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to get (without the `<div id="acme_usersbundle_usertype">`):

```
<form method="post" action="/acme/web/app_dev.php/admin/users_management/3">
    <label>Edit user</label>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" value="PUT" name="_method">

        <section>
            <label class="required" for="acme_usersbundle_usertype_username">
                Login
                <span class="required"> </span>
            </label>
            <div>
                <input id="acme_usersbundle_usertype_username" type="text" value="login" maxlength="255" required="required" name="acme_usersbundle_usertype[username]">
            </div>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

After using:

```
form_widget(form)
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean with container on the whole form. Maybe post a example, what you get now and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Added an example with explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For putting rows into the `<section>`, your approach is correct.

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <section>
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    </section>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

For using the `<fieldset>` instead of the `<div`> simply modify the `form_widget_compound` block and not more. not even the `form_widget`

```
{% block form_widget_compound %}
{% spaceless %}
    <fieldset {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% if form.parent is empty %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ block('form_rows') }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </fieldset>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_compound %}
```

This should do the trick ;)

> In Twig, every block needed is defined in a single template file ([form_div_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)) that lives inside the Twig Bridge. Inside this file, you can see every block needed to render a form and every default field type.

Comment: form_widget_compound that is what I was looking for, thanks a lot!!! May I ask where can you find a complete list of twig form blocks? I can't find it in Google...

Comment: Added the link to the default file with all blocks to my answer.

Comment: Man you're hella awesome! Unluckily the blocks are not documented :( . Make sure to come for a beer some day!

Comment: Yes, but most of the blocks are self-explanatory. If you have new question according to the blocks, simple post a new on stackoverflow. Oh and don't forget to accept my answer ;)